# Getting value of String in Jlist

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

How can I get the value of an item in this case String item that has been added to a JList? What I meanV

```
String[] coinNames ={"Quarters","Dimes","Nickels","Pennies"};
JList coinList = new JList (coinNames);
coinList[0] == "Quarters" ???????
```

Since I clearly can't reference it like a normal array, how might I go about getting the string value of coinlist[0]?

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple example to get just an index to your JList and display all your JList.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] coinNames ={"Quarters","Dimes","Nickels","Pennies"};
    JList coinList = new JList (coinNames);
    String myCoin = (String) coinList.getModel().getElementAt(0);
    System.out.println(myCoin);

    /* LIST AL YOUR COINNAMES */

    System.out.println("\nCoinList\n");

    for(int i =0; i < coinList.getModel().getSize(); i++){
        System.out.println((String) coinList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
    }

    coinNames[0] = "My new Value"; // Edit your CoinNames at index 0

    /* LIST AL YOUR NEW COINNAMES */

    System.out.println("\nNew coinList edited\n");

    for(int i =0; i < coinList.getModel().getSize(); i++){
        System.out.println((String) coinList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, also I hate to ask this but how would I go about changing a string that exists at a certain point in the list like      `coinList.getModel().getElementAt(i) = exampleString;`

Comment: No problem. Check my new answer. You can edit an element at a certain point now.

Answer (score 2):

```
coinList.getModel().getElementAt(0);
```

pls read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getModel--

EDIT: or simply take a look at the example at the op of the amnual page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

```
 // Create a JList that displays strings from an array

 String[] data = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
 JList<String> myList = new JList<String>(data);

 // Create a JList that displays the superclasses of JList.class, by
 // creating it with a Vector populated with this data

 Vector<Class<?>> superClasses = new Vector<Class<?>>();
 Class<JList> rootClass = javax.swing.JList.class;
 for(Class<?> cls = rootClass; cls != null; cls = cls.getSuperclass()) {
     superClasses.addElement(cls);
 }
 JList<Class<?>> myList = new JList<Class<?>>(superClasses);

 // The automatically created model is stored in JList's "model"
 // property, which you can retrieve

 ListModel<Class<?>> model = myList.getModel();
 for(int i = 0; i < model.getSize(); i++) {
     System.out.println(model.getElementAt(i));
 }
```

Comment: Wow, Java 6 is like WAY out of service (no longer maintained), you could at least link back to Java 8.  Also `Vector` was superseded way back in Java 1.3 in favour of `List`

Comment: JList doesn't changed the behavior from 6 to 8. But you are right... I was in the wrong version. I updated the links. ty
-- the code is not mine. It's the code from the documentation, and I didn't wanne change it, when I post the link to the source ;) so. sry for that, but I won't change it to list.

Comment: Actually, it has, it now has support for Generics since Java 7.  You might want to point where the code come from then, always a good habit, otherwise people start accusing of plagiarism ;)